# Gradle file did not change at all and now, I am unable to build the project

Tags: android, android-ndk, invocationtargetexception, kapt

I am trying to build my Android project. The problem is that nothing on my gradle file changed. And out of the blue, this error is not letting me build:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

I tried updating NDK on gradle and SDK tools, I set on Project Structure NDK location, I have tried plenty proposed solutions on StackOverflow with no success. That is why I am posting a new question.